# Matrices with same row reduced form - Show there's a sequence of row operations

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let us assume that Q and W are z x y matrices such that they have the same row reduced form. Prove that there exists a sequence of row operations that takes us from Q to W."

How would one prove this statement? Thank you.

Comment: I'm no expert, but a formal version of "we know row operations can take us from Q to rref(Q)=rref(W), and we know row operations can take us from W to rref(W)=rref(Q), so we just do the Q->rref(Q) and then just the steps from W->rref(W) backwards, which works because row operations are linear"?

Comment: Oh yes that is true? Would that suffice as a proof though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row operations which reduce a matrix to its row reduced form are all reversible, and achievable through premutiplication by an invertible matrix. So if $\ R\ $ is the common row reduced form of $\ Q\ $ and $\ W\ $, we must have:

\begin{eqnarray}
R &=& E_1\,E_2\dots E_r\, Q\ \ \mbox{and}\\
R &=& F_1\,F_2\dots F_s\, W\ ,
\end{eqnarray}

where $\ E_1, E_2,\dots E_r, F_1,F_2,\dots F_s\ $ are matrices by whose premultiplications each of the necessary row operations are effected. It follows that

\begin{eqnarray}
W &=& F_s^{-1}\,F_{s-1}^{-1}\dots F_1^{-1}\,R \\
&=& F_s^{-1}\,F_{s-1}^{-1}\dots F_1^{-1}\,E_1\,E_2\dots E_r\, Q\ .
\end{eqnarray}

That is, the sequence of row operations effected by the matrices $\ E_r, E_{r-1}, \dots E_1, F_1^{-1}, F_2^{-1},\dots F_s^{-1}\ $ will transform $\ Q\ $ into $\ W\ $.